# how to convert datetime by removing nanoseconds

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have sample **CSV** data which have **Time** in the following format

2014-04-29 00:00:01.933000,2014-04-29 00:00:01.933000

I can do pd.to_datetime(data['ts']) and also pd.DatetimeIndex(data['ts'])

but how to format the output as **%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S** or basically to be removed the nanoseconds.

This simple dateformatter seems to be missed out from all docs, I have read in pandas. I know the alternative is to convert to the float

```
np.floor(pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(sdfeed1['ts'])).astype(int64)/1e9)
```

I don't like this ugly approach. Is there any simple way to convert array of date-times to simple format. Simply like excel does without using any lambda functions.

pd.convert(...list of dates...,format = '....'), It should be as simple as this! Am I asking too much? Pushing np and lambda functions for this is overkill.

Comment: What is your queston: convert the datetime to a *string* without the nanoseconds (so a formatting issue), or convert it to a *datetime* without the nanoseconds (so a rounding issue)?

Comment: Here's the open issue to provide DatetimeIndex rounding as a function: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4314. Pretty straightforward to monkey-patch this in yourself. Appreciate pull-requests to implement as well!

Answer (score 3):

```
data['from_timestamp']=data['from_timestamp'].values.astype('datetime64[s]')
```

This will set the nanoseconds from the datetime64[ns] to 0. The end result will still be datetime64[ns], but the nanosecond is removed when astype() is called.

Answer (score 2):

how about this one.

```
pd.Timestamp("now").round('s')
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:

```
datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

This outputs the result as:

```
'2014-09-05 14:41:26'
```

Comment: then I have to do this....    pd.to_datetime(sdfeed['ts'])[0].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")      again sdfeed['ts'] is an array...why doesnt strftime work on the whole array? Again this will lead to lambda function!!

Comment: @coffeequant:- Indeed! It will not do it at once. You need to iterate through your array and do the same.

Comment: @coffeequant:- A second option which comes to my mind is to use `unicode(datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0))`

Answer (score 1):

Use `dateutil.parser` and then format datetime object

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> raw_text = '2014-04-29 00:00:01.933000 2014-04-29 00:00:01.933000 2014-04-29 00:00:02.308000 2014-04-29 00:00:02.308000 2014-04-29 00:00:03.308000 2014-04-29 00:00:03.308000 2014-04-29 00:00:06.792000 2014-04-29 00:00:06.792000 2014-04-29 00:00:07.480000 2014-04-29 00:00:07.480000 2014-04-29 00:00:08.355000 2014-04-29 00:00:08.355000 2014-04-29 00:00:15.027000 2014-04-29 00:00:15.027000 2014-04-29 00:00:15.917000 2014-04-29 00:00:15.917000 2014-04-29 00:00:22.558000 2014-04-29 00:00:22.558000'
>>> dates = raw_text.split()
>>> date_parts = 2
>>> for idx in xrange(0,len(dates),date_parts):
...     text = ' '.join(dates[idx:idx+date_parts])
...     dt = parse(text)
...     dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
... 
'2014-04-29 00:00:01'
'2014-04-29 00:00:01'
'2014-04-29 00:00:02'
'2014-04-29 00:00:02'
'2014-04-29 00:00:03'
'2014-04-29 00:00:03'
'2014-04-29 00:00:06'
'2014-04-29 00:00:06'
'2014-04-29 00:00:07'
'2014-04-29 00:00:07'
'2014-04-29 00:00:08'
'2014-04-29 00:00:08'
'2014-04-29 00:00:15'
'2014-04-29 00:00:15'
'2014-04-29 00:00:15'
'2014-04-29 00:00:15'
'2014-04-29 00:00:22'
'2014-04-29 00:00:22'
```

Note: `dateutil.parser` parse a date-string without specify pattern!!

```
>>> text = '2014/04/29 00:00:01.933000'
>>> dt = parse(text)
>>> dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
'2014-04-29 00:00:01'
>>> 
>>> text = '29/4/14 00:00:01.933000'
>>> dt = parse(text)
>>> dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
'2014-04-29 00:00:01'
```

Comment: its not a single datetime...its an array of datetimes

Comment: ts

2014-04-29 00:00:01.933000   2014-04-29 00:00:01.933000
2014-04-29 00:00:02.308000   2014-04-29 00:00:02.308000
2014-04-29 00:00:03.308000   2014-04-29 00:00:03.308000
2014-04-29 00:00:06.792000   2014-04-29 00:00:06.792000
2014-04-29 00:00:07.480000   2014-04-29 00:00:07.480000
2014-04-29 00:00:08.355000   2014-04-29 00:00:08.355000
2014-04-29 00:00:15.027000   2014-04-29 00:00:15.027000
2014-04-29 00:00:15.917000   2014-04-29 00:00:15.917000
2014-04-29 00:00:22.558000   2014-04-29 00:00:22.558000
Name: ts, dtype: datetime64[ns]